# Why position.y returns me wrong value?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want implement a simple animation, filling from bottom to top. For this I do:

```
let waterView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 568))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(waterView.layer.position.y)
    self.waterView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 50/255, green: 145/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1)
    self.view.addSubview(self.waterView)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        print(self.waterView.layer.position.y)
    })
}
```

And when I print it's `position.y` value, it returns me **284**! I do not understand why??? Why it doesn't return me **0**?

Is there any logic explanation?

Comment: You are printing the y-Position of the center of the rectangle `self.waterView.center.y`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**284 is valid value.**

Reason : You are setting

x=0

y = 0

widht = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width(suppose 320)

height = 568

So, center will be center(x,y) = (  (320-0)/2 , (568-0)/2  ) = (160,284)

You are trying to print **`waterView.center.y`**, that's why output is **`284`**.

Try to print **`waterView.frame.origin.y`** it will print **`0`**.

Comment: but it `print(waterView.layer.position.y)` returns me the same result. Look at my code again, please, in viewDidLoad

Comment: try to print self. waterView.layer.bounds.origin.y in viewDidLoad()

Comment: but in `viewDidLoad` this `print(self.waterView.layer.position.y)` returns again `284`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are printing `self.waterView.center.y` and on calculating the height you are giving to the view which is 568, then its center is 568/2 = 284

in order to print the y coordinate of the view "waterView" then please use : `print(waterView.frame.origin.y)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple answer, `position` of view's layer, not exactly, but, by default indicates center of view in parent coordinate system. For example:

```
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300))
print(v.layer.position.y)
```

will print `250`. It will print `0.0`, if you set `origin.y` and `height` to `0.0`, otherwise, formula for `position.y` is `position.y = origin.y + height / 2`

If you want origin, you need `view.origin` or `view.layer.origin`. If you want to move position to (0,0) you need to modify layer's anchorpoint, but why would you for that simple task.

BTW, don't use `CGRectMake()`, use initializers, as in my example.